# Ejecutar función scrip según el id del elemento abuelo

Tags: javascript, jquery

La función se ejecuta solo  en la primer tr.  necesito  que se ejecute en todos  según el elemento abuelo o el  id del   al que este pertenesca
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
                function Sumar() {  
                    var n1 = document.getElementById('Costo').value;  
                    var n2 = document.getElementById('iva').value;  
                    var multi = parseInt(n1) * n2;  
                    var suma = parseInt(n1) + multi;  
                    document.getElementById('total').value = suma;  

                }  
                setInterval('Sumar()',100);  

            </script>
```

y este el input y tr

```
<tr id='row'>  
<td>  
<input type="text" class="form-control Cost" id="Costo" required="required" readonly="readonly" name="BX_NAM[]"> 
</td>  
<td>
<input type="text" required="required" id="iva" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" value="0.16" readonly="readonly"   name="BX_ag[]">  
</td>  
<td>
```

Comment: Cómo se generan los <tr> ? Debes tratar de agregar un ID distinto para cada .tr así como para cada .input
Podes utilizar un identificador el número de fila por ejemplo.

Comment: @Edopex lo que planteas es simplemente incorrecto, es una problemática que se tiene que solucionar mediante el uso de clases, por otro lado; emanuel, ¿porque usas un `setInterval` en lugar de algún evento como `onchange` o `input`?

Comment: De echo  cada <tr>  tiene un id diferente al  generarlo. el  SetInterval solo  lo utilizo momentáneamente en lo  que logro arreglar esto.por eso lo  que quiero  realizar el  como generar  función sumar en el  en el input correspondiente al  id del  tr donde se encuentra no se si me  explico.